# Android - how do i detect android is going to screen lock mode, where i need to complete a job at that stage

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an apps which is working fine but the problem is when it goes automatically to screen lock mode, i need to complete a job. Unlock screen i can detect using intent receiver but cant find how to know when its going to screen lock mode via power button press or automatically.

Is there a way to find it? I have tried following but no luck.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNjfdhotDimScreen");   



@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  wl.release();
  Toast.makeText(this, "up!!!!." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  vibrator.vibrate(2000);

}//End of onPause

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  wl.acquire();
  Toast.makeText(this, "up!!!!." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  vibrator.vibrate(2000);

}//End of onResume
```

EDIT: tried but no luck under onCreate

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
  Toast.makeText(this, "up!!!!." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  vibrator.vibrate(2000);      
} else {
 //it is not locked
  Toast.makeText(this, "up!!!!." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  vibrator.vibrate(2000);      
}
```

EDIT: You cant do 3 things with mainfest because of system performence, to still do it one has to use following dynamic injection.

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mPowerKeyReceiver = null;

  private void registBroadcastReceiver() {
      final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
      /** System Defined Broadcast */
      theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
      theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

      mPowerKeyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              String strAction = intent.getAction();

              if (strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                  // > Your playground~!
                Log.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>onDestroy");
              }
          }
      };

      getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mPowerKeyReceiver, theFilter);
  }

  private void unregisterReceiver() {
      int apiLevel = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);

      if (apiLevel >= 7) {
          try {
              getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(mPowerKeyReceiver);
          }
          catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
              mPowerKeyReceiver = null;
          }
      }
      else {
          getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(mPowerKeyReceiver);
          mPowerKeyReceiver = null;
      }
  }
```

Comment: what does "complete a job" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a Broadcast Reciever for "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" and "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF".

Comment: FYI: android core do not allow to those 3 thing via Mainfest. Just tried and did not worked what you have mentioned But i have work out of it which is working by injecting dynamically those three methods.